# How do I add parameters to the code in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Need to add a record to the tblMeetings table, then have that ID column (PK, Int, no null) from tblMeetings to add to tblVotings table to the Meeting_ID column (int, not null). the first 2 query blocks of code work! The last Protected Sub "ftrInsert_Click"  block does not work where I am trying to pass the parameters from one table to the other. I do not get an error and the record inserts to the tblMeetings but not the tblVotings.
My whole aspx.vb page of code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _NewMeetings
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim WithEvents ftrInsert As New Button

Protected Sub GridView2_RowCommand(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As           System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "ftrInsert" Then
        'call the insert sub (sender is the gridview that called the rowCommand, 
        'UsersDS is the name of our sqlDataSource on the page
        gvQuickInsert(sender, SqlDataSource2)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub gvQuickInsert(ByRef gv As GridView, ByRef ds As SqlDataSource)
    Dim paramsArr As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim controlsArr As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim col As Integer = 0
    Dim footrow As GridViewRow = gv.FooterRow

    Try
        Dim ix As Integer = 0
        For ix = 0 To gv.Columns.Count
            Dim d As DataControlField = gv.Columns(ix)
            If d.InsertVisible = True Then
                If footrow.Cells(ix).Controls(1) IsNot Nothing Then
                    paramsArr.Add(d.SortExpression.ToString)
                controlsArr.Add(footrow.Cells(ix).Controls(1))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    ds.InsertParameters.Clear()

    Dim ii As Integer = 0
    For Each contr As Object In controlsArr
        If contr.GetType.Name.ToLower.Contains("textbox") Then
            ds.InsertParameters.Add(paramsArr(ii), TryCast(contr, TextBox).Text)
        ElseIf contr.GetType.Name.ToLower.Contains("dropdownlist") Then
            ds.InsertParameters.Add(paramsArr(ii), _
          TryCast(contr, DropDownList).SelectedValue)
        ElseIf contr.GetType.Name.ToLower.Contains("checkbox") Then
            If TryCast(contr, CheckBox).Checked Then
                ds.InsertParameters.Add(paramsArr(ii), 1)
            Else
                ds.InsertParameters.Add(paramsArr(ii), 0)
            End If
        End If
        ii = ii + 1
    Next
    ds.Insert()
    gv.DataBind()
End Sub
Protected Sub ftrInsert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ftrInsert.Click

    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ServiceLine_CommitteeConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)

        'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblVotings VALUES (@
        Dim Meeting_ID As New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
        Dim Committee_ID As New SqlParameter("@Comm", SqlDbType.Int)
        Dim Member_Name As New SqlParameter("@Member", SqlDbType.NVarChar)

        'Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) SELECT M.ID AS Meeting_ID, C.ID AS Committee_ID, CM.Full_Name AS Member_Name FROM tblCommitteeName AS C INNER JOIN tblMeetings AS M ON M.ContractCategory = C.Contract_Category AND M.Committee = C.Committee_Name INNER JOIN tblCommitteeMembers AS CM ON CM.Committee = M.Committee WHERE (M.ID IN (@ID)) and (C.ID IN (@Comm)) and (CM.Full_Name IN (@Member))", con)

        Meeting_ID.Value = 1
        Committee_ID.Value = 1
        Member_Name.Value = 1

        cmd.Parameters.Add(Meeting_ID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Committee_ID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Member_Name)
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()

        Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If con.state = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: It looks like your select parameters are out of order. `SELECT C.ID, M.ID, CM.FULL_NAME` doesn't look like it lines up with `insert into tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name)`. Given that `C.ID` is the `ID` of the `tblCommitteeName` and `M.ID` is the `ID` of `tblMeetings`. I'm not sure if that is the issue you are trying to solve but its just something I noticed.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the insert into statement. Now I just need to know how to put in the parameter for the Meeting ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters in SQL statements is fairly straight forward, but there are a couple rules that you have to remember.

1. Parameters must be added to the command in the order that they appear in the SQL statement
2. Parameter names must match exactly how they are referenced in the SQL
3. Parameter sizes should match the values they are given in the database. Not very important for numbers but extremely important for strings.

Most commonly those are the three issues that people new to SQL parameters will run into.

Here's an example of using SQL Parameters that you should be able to dissect to get what you want.

```
Dim strConnection As String = "ConnString"
Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl(Col1) VALUES (@p_Para1)", con)
    Dim p As New SqlParameter("@p_Para1", SqlDbType.Int, 8)
    p.value = 1
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
End Using
```

Your second error("Invalid column name 'Meeting_ID'. Invalid column name 'Committee_ID'. Invalid column name 'Member_Name'.") I think is becuase of the way ou have your `WHERE` clause set up.

So instead of:

```
INSERT INTO tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) 
    SELECT M.ID AS Meeting_ID, C.ID AS Committee_ID, CM.Full_Name AS Member_Name 
    FROM tblCommitteeName AS C INNER JOIN tblMeetings AS M ON M.ContractCategory = C.Contract_Category AND M.Committee = C.Committee_Name INNER JOIN tblCommitteeMembers AS CM ON CM.Committee = M.Committee 
    WHERE (Meeting_ID IN (@ID)) and (Committee_ID IN (@Comm)) and (Member_Name IN (@Member))
```

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) 
    SELECT M.ID AS Meeting_ID, C.ID AS Committee_ID, CM.Full_Name AS Member_Name 
    FROM tblCommitteeName AS C INNER JOIN tblMeetings AS M ON M.ContractCategory = C.Contract_Category AND M.Committee = C.Committee_Name INNER JOIN tblCommitteeMembers AS CM ON CM.Committee = M.Committee 
    WHERE (M.ID IN (@ID)) and (C.ID IN (@Comm)) and (CM.Full_Name IN (@Member))
```

Comment: Isn't that c# or c++ code? I need the parameter based on VB.

Comment: Also, can I just create a parameter for Meeting_ID or do I have to create a parameter for all of the inserted fields?

Comment: The example is in VB. I only included the relevant portion so you will need to drop that snippet into your function. You will need to create a `SqlParameter` variable for each parameter in the SQL string you are executing. So if you are inserting 4 values and want each one to be a parameter then you will need to instantiate 4 `SqlParameter` variables and add each one to the `Parameters` collection on the `SqlCommand`

Comment: I used the code you posted. I have edited my code on top so you can see it and the error I now receive.

Comment: Dee: The error you are getting is because you are not supplying a value for your parameters. Un-comment those lines and update your question with the error that gives you.

Comment: I get this error:
SQLexception was unhandled by user code.
Invalid column name 'Meeting_ID'.

Invalid column name 'Committee_ID'.

Invalid column name 'Member_Name'.

Comment: I believe the issue there is with your `WHERE` clause. Check the edits for a possible fix.

Comment: When I change the WHERE clause to:
(M.ID IN (@ID)) and (C.ID IN (@Comm)) and (CM.Full_Name IN (@Member)). The error disappears but no records get added to the table.

Comment: Run the query without the insert clause directly against your database with hard coded values in the `WHERE` clause. I am guessing the database won't bring back any records.